# Is using ElasticSearch and Azure Search as regular data stores combined with search appropriate?

Tags: elasticsearch, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

We are still deciding on ElasticSearch on an Azure VM or Azure Search service to act as our search repository.  However, for user accounts, etc., is there any need to create a separate db (in SQL Azure or even another noSQL db)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no need to create a separate db account in order to us Azure Search (or ElasticSearch on Azure VM).  Azure Search is a REST API based service where you push your data to be "indexed" at which point it becomes searchable, also through this REST API.  The only time you might need a SQL account that I can think of is to use our new Indexer that will automatically ingest data (and data changes) into Azure Search from your Azure SQL or SQL Server on Azure VM database.

Comment: I should add to this that you authenticate using an "api-key" that is provided when you create the Azure Search service.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking is whether you can use Elasticsearch/Azure Search as your primary store for everything in an app, not just searchable data.

You can certainly do it. There are a few aspects you need to keep in mind (I'm sure there are others besides this):

1. Durability: when search indexes are just an index sometimes it's fine to run with no replicas or just 1 replica. If you want strong durability you probably want at least 3 total copies of the index to ensure availability and resilience to index corruption and things like that.
2. Consistency. Elasticsearch has a weak consistency model which also surfaces in Azure Search. You need to write your application taking into account this fact, which can make some scenarios tricky. Other stores such as SQL and DocumentDB offer the option for strict consistency which is easier to work with for a primary store.